# generate the report in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, testng

how can I generate the report after executing test cases in the selenium web driver. I am trying Test NG for generating report but I have to write different code to get the report?

Comment: When you execute the suite as testng suite you will get the report by default. Do you want to add more things to the report?

Comment: How do you run your tests? Are you're using Eclipse, Jenkins, Maven?

Comment: I am using eclipse. I wrote the java program. no I need to run it in testng.How can I run it?

Comment: Configure TestNG in eclipse. Go through http://testng.org/doc/index.html. There are a lot to learn there regarding testng.

Comment: @ArunKumar how do you run the test? Do you run it as testng suite. If you do the result should get generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven with Surefire plugin (which I strongly recommend), report is always located in `target/surefire-reports/index.html`. If that is not enough for your than you can use [ReportNG](http://reportng.uncommons.org/) library which is supposed to have more convenient reports in HTML format.